# C regex not matched

Tags: c, regex

I'm trying to match this regex `^%-?\+?#?0?$` with `regexec`, it works fine on [this site](https://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/golang/index.html), but something might be wrong because regexec doesn't work :

```
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    regex_t regex;
    if (regcomp(&regex, "^%-?\\+?#?0?$", 0) != 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    const int match = regexec(&regex, "%-", 0, NULL, REG_EXTENDED);
    if (match == 0) {
        puts("Matched !");
    }
    else {
        puts("Not found !");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This example shall display "Matched", but it says "Not found".
Does the problem come from my regex ?

Comment: what text are you trying to match, can you give an example?

Comment: All these examples must work :
%
%-
%+
%-+
%#
%-#
%+#
%-+#
%0
%-0
%-+0
%#0
%-#0
%+#0
%-+#0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `REG_EXTENDED` flag should be set when compiling the regex with `regcomp`, not on matching it with `regexec`. If you do that, it works, so:

```
if (regcomp(&regex, "^%-?\\+?#?0?$", REG_EXTENDED) != 0) {
    return -1;
}

const int match = regexec(&regex, "%-", 0, NULL, 0);
```

(I don't know whether POSIX mandates concrete values for the flags, but in my implementation, the compilation flag `REG_EXTENDED` has the same value as the matching flag `REG_NOTBOL`, which always fails to match the beginning of the string with `^`.)

Comment: No change, I still have a wrong output.

Comment: Well, it [worked](https://ideone.com/euBc0c) for me.

Comment: Thanks to what you wrote about flags, I removed start and end anchors and it works now

Comment: It should work with the `^$` anchors; the match will yield false positives without them.

Comment: So what can I do ? Is there any flag I can use ? It it can help, I'm compiling under WSL Ubuntu (GCC 11.2.0).

Comment: In the answer you have written and now deleted, you still have the `REG_EXTENDED` flag set in `regexec`. Set that to zero, as my code above does. (That's what my comment about flags was really about: `REG_EXTENDED` is interpreted as `REG_NOTBOL` when used erroneously in `regexec`.)

Comment: (Finally, ther's always to option [not to use regex](https://ideone.com/qzBphk) at all.)

Answer (score 0):

If some will read this page later, the final code is :

```
int main(void) {
    regex_t regex;
    if (regcomp(&regex, "^%-?\\+?#?0?$", REG_EXTENDED) != 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    const int match = regexec(&regex, "%-", 0, NULL, 0);
    if (match == 0) {
        puts("Matched !");
    }
    else {
        puts("Not found !");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I added the REG_EXTENDED flag when compiling regex, but removed it when executed.